# setInterval increases in speed each time triggered

Tags: javascript

I am teaching myself javascript and have a div which travels across the screen each time the space bar is pressed. However each time the space bar is pressed the speed increases, I'm confused as to why this is, what am I missing to keep the speed constant?

```
        window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        switch (event.key) {
        case ' ':
        if (posLeft > canvasWidth - 100 || Rocket.style.visibility != 'hidden') {
            Rocket.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        }
        else {
            Rocket.style.visibility = 'visible';
            console.log(posLeft);
            Rocket.style.left = (Player.offsetLeft + Player.offsetWidth) + 'px';
            Rocket.style.top = (Player.offsetTop + Player.offsetHeight / 2.5) + 'px';
            setInterval(function () {
                if (rocketLeft < canvasWidth) {
                    rocketLeft++;
                    console.log(rocketLeft);
                    Rocket.style.left = parseInt(Rocket.style.left, 10) + 1 + 'px';
                }
            });
            rocketLeft = 0;
            break;
        }
        };
        });
```

Comment: Since you never use `clearInterval`, you register an _additional_ series of function executions whenever the space bar is pressed. This gives the impression of increased speed.

Comment: Because every time this event handler fires, it creates a new independent interval which moves the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Heiko Theißen for pointing out that clearInterval was missing, I have updated the code, I'm sure it could be done a lot better but this works.

```
let fireRocket = '';
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  switch (event.key) {
    case ' ':
    if (posLeft > canvasWidth - 100 || Rocket.style.visibility != 'hidden') {
       Rocket.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
    else {
      Rocket.style.visibility = 'visible';
      console.log(posLeft);
      Rocket.style.left = (Player.offsetLeft + Player.offsetWidth) + 'px';
      Rocket.style.top = (Player.offsetTop + Player.offsetHeight / 2.5) + 'px';
      setInterval(function () {
        if (rocketLeft < canvasWidth) {
           rocketLeft++;
           console.log(rocketLeft);
           Rocket.style.left = parseInt(Rocket.style.left, 10) + 1 + 'px';
        }
      });
      if (rocketLeft >= 10) { clearInterval(fireRocket);
      rocketLeft = 0;
      break;
      }
   };
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your code and accept this answer to be helpful to people with the same question! https://stackoverflow.com/tour https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer